# Loop a function and bind together Pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, for-loop

I have a function that connects to an SQL database and fetch data from a table. I aim to loop that function over an iterator to make the same query on different tables. The function works, but the for loop below do not return anything. I'm new to Python and I'm sure I miss something fundamental here.

Example Code-

```
def func(years):
  
    conn = pyodc.connect()
      sql_query = """ SELECT TOP 100 X
                      FROM table_""" + years
      df = pd.Dataframe()
      if len(df) == 0:
         df = pd.read_sql(sql_query, conn)
         df['year'] = years
      else:
         df_temp = df.copy()
         temp = pd.read_sql_query)sql_query, conn)
         temp['year'] = years
         df = temp.append(df_temp)
    
      return df

loop = ['2017', '2018']

for year in loop:
    func(year)
```

Comment: new to programming or only python? your function definition is wrong, I would expect `def func(year):` if you want to call it in your loop in the way you are.  where does `years` come from in your function? you `sql_query=f"select top 100 x from table_{year}"`.  there are typos - close bracket where there should be an open bracket.  most probably your issue,  you are not assigning result of your function call to a variable.  ie `df = func(year)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to pass an argument to the function for it to accept and loop over. Also you might want to consider `pd.concat` so you can assign a variable to your dataframe.

So something like this would work and is cleaner:

```
def select_top(year):
    conn = pyodc.connect()
    sql_query = "SELECT TOP 100 X FROM table_{}".format(year)

    df = pd.read_sql(sql_query, conn)
    df['year'] = years

    return df

years = ['2017', '2018']

data = pd.concat([select_top(year) for year in years])
```

It will loop over the years and concatenates all your dataframes into 1.

Answer (score 1):

You need to pass `year` as an argument to the `func` function as follows-

```
def func(year):
      conn = pyodc.connect()
      sql_query = """ SELECT TOP 100 X
                      FROM table_{}""".format(years)
      df = pd.Dataframe()
      if len(df) == 0:
         df = pd.read_sql(sql_query, conn)
         df['year'] = years
      else:
         df_temp = df.copy()
         temp = pd.read_sql_query(sql_query, conn)
         temp['year'] = years
         df = temp.append(df_temp)

      return df

loop = ['2017', '2018']

for year in loop:
    func(year)
```

For more details on passing arguments to functions, refer [here](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_functions.htm).

Your code has some other logical errors too-

1. You're creating an empty dataframe before the if condition. It'll always set the if condition True.
2. You're not assigning the return value of your function to any variable.
3. You might need to use `df_temp` instead of `df` at some places.
4. You're not passing `df` as a function parameter (if you wish to modify it in the function). For doing so, you'll need to create an empty dataframe before the `for` loop as well.

Comment: Sorry, I missed write the argument. Thanks for the four pointers on logical errors.